# Entity Framework Profiler unable to determine provider name

Tags: entity-framework-6, profiler

I'm giving Entity Framework Profiler from Hibernating Rhinos a try.

Data access runs fine as long as the profiler is not initialized. As soon as I do register it, I get failures stating:

"Unable to determine the provider name for provider factory of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientFactory'. Make sure that the ADO.NET provider is installed or registered in the application config.
"

Already tried adding the following snippet to the config file:

```
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SqlClient" />
      <add name="SqlClient Data Provider"
           invariant="System.Data.SqlClient"
           description=".Net Framework Data Provider for SqlServer"
           type="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientFactory, System.Data,   
     Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
      />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
```

But this doesn't change anything.